# How to map each DocuSign request to envelopeId

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to implement a DocuSign API app to send documents to our clients for e-signature.  In  my application, I need to send one document to each client for e-signature. For example, an agreement doc where user will sign and agree to our terms and conditions.

So I will be sending the same document to each client and I assume I will be receiving a unique envelopeId for each individual request.

So how do you keep track of which envelopeId is associated with which user?

Can you send a custom tag in the request and receive it back in response to track it?

Answer (score 1):

Most DocuSign users build a fully functional integration.

Integration such as Salesforce, CRM and other products that integrate DocuSign into their system track it either through an Envelope Custom Field (with their internal application record information) or they document the envelopeId responses and store them in their application.

Either way will work out just the same, it's all on how you want your integration to work.

---

Here is a quick sample call on how to create an envelope from a template with a text custom field

```
{
    "emailSubject": "Just a test envelope",
    "status": "sent",
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
            {
                "name": "InternalToolNumber",
                "required": true,
                "show": false,
                "value": 123456789
            }
        ]
    },
    "templateId": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "john.doe@emaildomain.com",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "roleName": "Signer 1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Can please tell me how do you create envelope custom field? If there are any links to previous posts which explains it will help as well. Here is what I am doing but I do not get back value of my custom field. I receive only envelope Id. I tried using GET on customFieldsUri but that also comes back blank.

Comment: Request body {"accountId":"914551","emailSubject":"API Call that uses a Template","templateId":" B8F8E670-3758-4657-8BC7-B71A661B3C6C","templateRoles":[{"roleName":"Signer","name":"SignerUser","email":"signer@test.com"},{"roleName":"CC","name":"ccUser","email":"test@test.com"}],"documents":[{"documentId":"1","name":"test.pdf"}],"status":"sent","transactionId":"12345","customFields": {"textCustomFields": [{"name": "App Number","required": "true","show": "true","value": "1201230123"}]}}

Comment: Added how you do it on an envelope level for templates. The same node applies for non-templates and composite templates call as well.